# fill multiple nsmutabledictionary with data from API

Tags: ios

i saved results from API to nsmutabledictionary. In this API is paging after 15 results (1,2,3, etc).

I need to fill resultDictionary with results from API.

My code:

```
        self.resultDictionary = [[NSDictionary alloc] init];
        self.resultDictionary = [self.api sendDataViaPostAndFormDataWithTwoParameters:@"email" with:[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] valueForKey:@"email"] parameterTwo:@"heslo" with:[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] valueForKey:@"heslo"] onUrl:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://***", [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] valueForKey:@"id"], [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] valueForKey:@"token"], page] withMethod:@"POST" success:^(BOOL success) {
    } failure:^(NSString *fail) {
        NSLog(@"%@", fail);
    }];
```

It works fine - it shows 15 results. But, when i scroll down in tableview and after 15 index load next page in api, it shows next 15 results. I need to join both (30results / old and new).

I tried add entries... but no effect.

Could you help me please?

edit:

my rest of code with edit from Ashish

```
@implementation testingTableViewController {
NSMutableDictionary * resultDictionary;
}

-(void)reloadData:(int)page {
// set selected NO
if ([[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] valueForKey:@"id"] == NULL) {

    loginViewController *login = [[loginViewController alloc] init];
    login.hidesBottomBarWhenPushed = YES;
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:login animated:NO];

} else {
    SHOW_NAVIGATION_BAR

    self.api = [[API alloc] init];

    self.temp = [self.api sendDataViaPostAndFormDataWithTwoParameters:@"email" with:[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] valueForKey:@"email"] parameterTwo:@"heslo" with:[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] valueForKey:@"heslo"] onUrl:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://*****/=&page=%d", [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] valueForKey:@"id"], [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] valueForKey:@"token"], page] withMethod:@"POST" success:^(BOOL success) {
        NSLog(@"OK načteno");


    } failure:^(NSString *fail) {
        NSLog(@"%@", fail);
    }];
}
}
-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
[super viewWillAppear:animated];

resultDictionary = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];
self.temp = [[NSDictionary alloc] init];
[self reloadData:1];

[self.tableView reloadData];
[self.tableView setNeedsLayout];

}

- (void)viewDidLoad {
[super viewDidLoad];

    [self.tableView registerClass:[TableViewCell class] forCellReuseIdentifier:@"cell"];


self.chatButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
self.commentButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];

UIButton *commentButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
commentButton.frame = CGRectMake(15, 0, 20, 20);
[commentButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"chat"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[commentButton addTarget:self action:@selector(page1) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
[self.view addSubview:commentButton];

UIButton *chatButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
chatButton.frame = CGRectMake(65, 0, 20, 20);
[chatButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"like"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[chatButton addTarget:self action:@selector(page2) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
[self.view addSubview:chatButton];

}


-(void)page1 {
[self reloadData:1];
    [resultDictionary addEntriesFromDictionary:self.temp];
[self.tableView reloadData];
}

-(void)page2 {
[self reloadData:2];
[resultDictionary addEntriesFromDictionary:self.temp];
[self.tableView reloadData];
}
```

When click at first button, result is 15, if i again click on first button, result is still 15 instead 30

Thank you for any response

Answer (score 0):

As per your code

```
self.resultDictionary = [[NSDictionary alloc] init];
        self.resultDictionary = [self.api sendDataViaPostAndFormDataWithTwoParameters:@"email" with:[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] valueForKey:@"email"] parameterTwo:@"heslo" with:[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] valueForKey:@"heslo"] onUrl:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://***", [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] valueForKey:@"id"], [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] valueForKey:@"token"], page] withMethod:@"POST" success:^(BOOL success) {
    } failure:^(NSString *fail) {
        NSLog(@"%@", fail);
    }];
```

You are not using `NSMutableDictionary`. Create instance of `NSMutableDictionary` at top of the class.

```
    NSMutableDictionary * resultDictionary;
```

Initialize it in viewDidLoad method

```
self.resultDictionary = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];
```

Finally in your code for fetching result form server.

```
NSDictionary *tempDict = [self.api sendDataViaPostAndFormDataWithTwoParameters:@"email" with:[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] valueForKey:@"email"] parameterTwo:@"heslo" with:[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] valueForKey:@"heslo"] onUrl:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://***", [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] valueForKey:@"id"], [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] valueForKey:@"token"], page] withMethod:@"POST" success:^(BOOL success) {

             [self.resultDictionary addEntriesFromDictionary:tempDict];

        } failure:^(NSString *fail) {
            NSLog(@"%@", fail);
        }];
```

Comment: What is return type of this sendDataViaPostAndFormDataWithTwoParameters method. The issue is, I think this method is executing asynchronously thats why you need to set self.resultDictionary once result is fetched from server.

Comment: return type of this method is NSDictionary and use     NSMutableDictionary* json = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:returnData
                                                         options:kNilOptions
                                                           error:&error];